# Sum of all even values of an array?AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to sum all the even values from my array, so here is an example of it:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 1
  [2] => 1
  [3] => 1
  [4] => 4
  [5] => 6
  [6] => 6
)
```

looking a way to sum all from same value:

```
Array
(
  [1] => 4
  [4] => 1
  [6] => 2
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var buckets:Object = {};

var data:Array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    if(!buckets[data[i]]) {
        buckets[data[i]] = 1;
    } else {
        buckets[data[i]]++;
    }
}

trace(buckets);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sum:uint = 0;                                    //Setting the sum value to 0;
for(var i:uint = 0; i < nameOfArray.length; i++){    //Loops trough the array

    if(nameOfArray[i] % 2 == 0 ){                    //If the number is an even number

    sum+=nameOfArray[i];                             //Add that even number to the sum variable
    }

}

trace(sum)                                           // Prints out the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map & loop through your array, adding the values into you're map. If you don't know what a map is, it is basically a collection type. It is created using a pair, using a unique key & a value associated with it. In your case, the unique key will be the number value in the array and the value will be the number of times it appears (frequency).